# dump a mediawiki from external

Tags: backup, mediawiki

There are some possibilities how to backup or dump your Mediawiki when you have server access. But is there a tool, that I can use to dump a complete MediaWiki Instance from external? I know, there is the Specials:Export page, but therefore I would need all the names of Wiki Pages, so Iam looking for a tool that finds these names and does the export of this pages. Preferably I just give the link of a MediaWiki instance to the tool and it does all the work.

Comment: You could try the [Maintenance extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Maintenance).

Comment: No I can't, because I dont have any special access, it is about dumping a public Wiki from outside :)

Comment: In that case, use a bot ([Pywikibot](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot) is the most popular choice). [Generate a family file](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot/Third-party_Wiki_Quick_Start) for the wiki, run [`pageimport.py`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot/pageimport.py) with the [`-start`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot/pagegenerators.py) option for all namespaces, and use [MediaWikiAuth](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:MediaWikiAuth) to migrate users.